# Des-habilitar con advertencia en Modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal

tengo un problema y es que al hacer clic al modal quiero que me cargue el id de  dicho proveedor, es necesario debido a que es una advertencia para desactivar o activar dicho proveedor, dejo el código

Este es el código con el cual muestro una tabla con los proveedores y asigno los botones para realizar tanto la acción de editar un proveedor como poder eliminarlo sin embargo con esta ultima tengo problemas ya que es con esta la cual tiene un modal, necesito pesarla el dato de la fila en la cual estoy dando click para que un vez dentro del modal efectivamente desactive dicho proveedor y no otro de la base de datos.

```
 function listado_proveedores(){
$conexion   = new connex();
$seleccion  = "SELECT Proveedor.*,Estado.Descripcion_Estado FROM Proveedor inner join Estado on Proveedor.ID_Estado=Estado.ID_Estado order by Proveedor.ID_Estado DESC";
$consulta   = $conexion->query($seleccion);
//Función while para capturar uno a uno las filas resultantes de la consulta
$lista = "";
while($fila = $conexion->row($consulta))
{
  //concateno a la variable creada los resultados de la fila
  $id = $fila['ID_Estado'];
  $lista .= '<tr>
  <td>'.$fila['Rut'].'</td>
  <td>'.$fila['Razon_Social'].'</td>
  <td>'.$fila['Comuna'].'</td>
  <td>'.$fila['Descripcion_Estado'].'</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editar('.$fila['ID_Proveedor'].')">Modificar</button></td>';
 if ($id ==2){
 $lista .='<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_hab">Habilitar</button></td>
 </tr>';
 }
 if ($id ==1){
 $lista .='<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_des">Deshabilitar</button></td>
 </tr>';
 }
}
echo $lista;
$conexion->cerrar();
```

}?>

Este es el código de los modal(son 2, uno para habilitar y otro para des-habilitar) así como de la tabla donde muestro la información

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/menus/jQuery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../js/menus/cssDatatable.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/menus/jQueryDatatable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/compra/proveedor.js"></script>
<?php
    include '../../db/compras/select_tabla_prov.php';
?>

<div id="page-inner" align="center">
    <div align="center" class="row">
        <h1>Proveedores</h1>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="left">
    <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="ingresar_proveedor();">Nuevo</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="volver();">Volver</button></td>
    <br/>
    <br/>
        <table id="tablita2" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead style="background-color: #ccffcc;">
                <tr>
                    <th>RUT</th>
                    <th>Razon Social Proveedor</th>
                    <th>Comuna</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Modificacion</th>
                    <th>Desabilitar/Habilitar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    listado_proveedores();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
!------MODAL DONDE HABILITAMOS PROVEEDOR----!
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_hab" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Habilitación Proveedor</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ¿Realmente desea habilitar dicho proveedor?
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cerrar_modal()">SI</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
!------MODAL DONDE DESHABILITAMOS PROVEEDOR----!
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_des" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Deshabilitacion Proveedor</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ¿Realmente desea deshabilitar dicho proveedor?
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cerrar_modal()">SI</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Básicamente necesito que cuando presione el botón dehabilitar me cargue el modal correspondiente y sepa que estoy haciendo clic y me refiero a esa fila y no a otra.

Estas son las funciones que ocupo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tablita2').DataTable(); 
});
function ingresar_proveedor(){
    $("#page-wrapper").load("vista/modulos/ingreso/ingreso_proveedor.php")
}
function MostrarModal(){
    $('#modal_contacto').modal('show')//mostramos el modal
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
}
function volver(){
    $("#page-wrapper").load("vista/menus/inicio.php")
}
function editar(id){
    $("#page-wrapper").load('vista/modulos/modificacion/modificacion_proveedor.php?valor='+id);
}
```

Comment: busca this para que sirve

Comment: Investigare, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: mira no es algo dificil pero si es algo de pensar tienes que seleccionar el tr donde tienes todos los datos vas apuntar a ese <tr> y te recomiendo cuando lo obtengas por javascript le crees una clase a ese tr para que al momento de querer desabilitar le pasas el nombre de la clase  ala funcion desabilitar

Comment: esto debes tener en el <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>ccc</td><td>habilitar</td><td>desabilitar</td></tr>  al pasar this vas a tener la fila que escogiste

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamte Carlos, tomare el consejo en cuenta, y si, la verdad debo suponer que es algo no muy complejo pero si da que pensar, saludos amigo.

Answer (score 0):

aqui tienes un ejemplo

```
                <tr>
              <td><?php echo $vacante['nombreComercial'].'-'.str_pad($vacante['mes'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.$vacante['anio'].'-'.str_pad($vacante['folio'], 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vacante["puesto"]?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vacante["nombrePerfil"]?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vacante["estado"]?></td>
              <td><?php 
                $puntos = 0;
                foreach ($vacante['puntaje'] as $puntuaje) {
                      $puntos += $puntuaje;
                    }
                echo $english_format_number = number_format($puntos, 2, '.', '');    
                ?></td>
              <td class = "text-center"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="verMatch2(this,'<?php echo base64_encode(json_encode($datosSolicitud)); ?>','<?php echo base64_encode($vacante['idPerfil']); ?>');"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
```

aca lo obtengo con javascript (data) es otro archivo php que trae datos, el remove es como si fuera un reset para que remueva (tr.tmp)

```
function verMatch2(elemento,solicitudEmpleo,idPerfil){
$("tr.tmp").remove();
tmp = $(elemento); fila = tmp.closest('tr');
$.ajax({
data: {solicitudEmpleo : solicitudEmpleo,idPerfil : idPerfil},
    url:   'index.php?accion=verMatch2',
        type:  'post',
    success:  function (data) {
        fila.after("<tr class='tmp'><td colspan='6'>"+data+"</td></tr>");
        $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(parametros);
    },
});
```

}